# Selecting a data-ng-bind with selenium for python

Tags: python-2.7, selenium

I'm trying to get the 0 value in this bit of code but can't seem to get it.

```
<div class="visits-column table-cell ng-binding" data-ng-bind="item.viewCounter">0</div>
```

I tried by xpath which does not work because the id seems to change when the value does.
I tried with css selector but it also does not work

> browser.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='msg-1239608978']/div[6]")
>   browser.find_element_by_css_selector('visits-column table-cell ng-binding').value (I also tried .text but it also does not work)

Would I have to do it by regex or is there something I'm missing ?

I tried looking for ng-binding but couldn't find much information relevant to my problem apart from giving time for the page to load

Thank you very much :) !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The css selector in your try is incorrect, you can try

```
browser.find_element_by_css_selector('.visits-column.table-cell.ng-binding')
```

`.text` on the above element might give the required value but you might have to play around with it.

Comment: Thank you ! I'll try that one as soon as I can get a hand on my code ! I've found a workaround with the page source + find, etc but it's not pretty ! I'll keep you tuned ! :)

Comment: browser.find_element_by_css_selector('.visits-column.table-cell.ng-binding').text does work ! :) the .value does not work however since webobject doesn't have this function !
Thank you very much !